# Does rain affect plants?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Does rain affect plants like flowers, shrubs, and saplings? I'm wondering if they get watered as if I had watered them with my own watering can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Weather#Rain) says when it doesnt rain, you must take extra care to water plants, so I'm assuming this means that the rain does in fact affect them.

[Here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Weather#Flowers) is the link that specifically says it waters the flowers.

Answer (score 5):

Rain waters flowers (which you can verify by the "sparkle" they sometimes give off), it will even restore "brown" wilted flowers the next day.

The only effect rain has on bushes is that (rarely, in the right season; april to september) snails will appear on bushes. Snails no longer appear on flowers, so this is important to note.

It does not affect bamboo or trees in any way.

Comment: What season do snails appear?

Comment: @Spectro added that to the answer; april - sept